# How to construct a confidence interval for the difference between two means of a two normally distributed RV $X,Y$, that are dependent on one another

Tags: confidence-interval

How to construct a confidence interval for the difference between two means of a two normally distributed RV $X,Y$, that are **dependent** on one another.

The variance is known

So we have:
$$X \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$$
$$Y \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$$

The question is: What is the $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for $\mu_x - \mu_y$?

My approach:

$$ E[X-Y)=E[X]-E[Y]=\mu_x - \mu_y$$
$$ \text{Var}[X-Y] = \text{Var}[X] + \text{Var}[Y] = \sigma_{x-y}^2 = \sigma_x^2 +\sigma_y^2 $$

Confidence interval is:

$$ \text{Confidence interval}(1-\alpha) = \left[ (\bar x-\bar y)\pm (Z_{1-\alpha/2}) \frac{\sqrt{\sigma_x^2 +\sigma_y^2}}{n}  \right]$$

However I don't know if this is the right approach? I have not used the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent. Should I use a paired t-test approach?

Comment: you need to be more careful with $Var(X-Y)$. It might be helpful to remember that $Var(X-Y)=Cov[X-Y,X-Y]$.

Comment: Start by proposing a test statistic and working out its sampling distribution in terms of $\mu_x,$ $\mu_y,$ and the covariance.  The latter plays an important role in the calculation to which @David just referred.